# Prevent RotateAnimation from resetting when cancelled

Tags: android, animation, frame, rotateanimation

I have a simple `RotateAnimation` to animate an `ImageView` indefinitely until I stop it. I have the animation set up as follows:

```
    Animation spin = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 1800.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    spin.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    spin.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    spin.setDuration(5000);
    imageView.setAnimation(spin);
```

When I call `imageView.cancelAnimation()`, is it possible for me to "freeze" the animation right at whatever frame it ended on (or whatever angle it's at) instead of having it reset to the first frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably better off wrapping your image contents in a `RotateDrawable` and setting it to the `ImageView` rather than using an animation.  You can still animate the transition by using a simple Handler to repeatedly call `setImageLevel()` to adjust the rotation angle.

When the time comes to freeze the animation, just stop posting to the `Handler` and the image will remain at its last set level value.  You can then restart if you like by resuming posts to the `Handler`.

Another option would be to create a custom `ViewGroup` and use `getChildStaticTransformation()` to apply a custom transform to a child `ImageView`.  You would still be handling the animation steps manually, so you can start/stop at any point you like, but `Transformation` is what the animation system uses to animate views so you might get results closer to that effect.

HTH

Comment: I guess this works. Only problem is that `RotateDrawable`s aren't as smooth when I try to use them as indeterminate progress bars. Do you know how I can increase the frame rate or speed of an indeterminate progress bar?

Comment: Not publicly.  `ProgressBar` uses an `AnimatedRotateDrawable`, which has these properties but is a hidden class.  I have added another option for transforming the view.  To get more smoothness you may need to manually call the methods on an Interpolator so you know how much to adjust the animation at each step.

Comment: Is there any example of using RotateDrawable?  I cannot find any in the android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I have an app that has to hold its rotation position after getting to its determined angle. I searched around for quite sometime and finally found that calling setFillAfter() method. This will stop the rotation from resetting.

```
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(startingPoint, value, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    image.setAnimation(rotate);

    rotate.setDuration(ROTATION_INTERVAL);
    rotate.setFillAfter(true);
```